# python (version 2.7.12 on ubuntu 16.04.1) - a function (similar to a lambda to return element 2) does not work as a key to sorted

Tags: python, function, sorting, lambda, key

I am experimenting with sorted keys, and trying to compare lambdas with functions to try and understand how lambdas work, and how sorted passes data to the replacable parameters in a lambda.

*Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here when I try to use the function instead of the lambda - it seems my assumption of how the parameters are passed to the lambda variable from the sorted keys is not valid if using a function.*

**Please see my code below and the output underneath it...**

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#--------------------------

sep = "\n----------------\n"

#--------------------------

student_tuples = [
        ('john', 'A', 15),
        ('jane', 'C', 10),
        ('dave', 'D', 12),
]

#--------------------------

print sep, "plain student_tuples on each line"
for x in student_tuples:
    print x, type(x)

#--------------------------

print sep, "show lambda is returning element 2 of each nested tuple"

for line in student_tuples:
    ld = (lambda x: x[2])(line)
    print ld, type(ld)

#--------------------------

print sep, "show sorted is passing each tuple to lambda in key="

st = sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda x: x[2])

for s in st:
    print s

#   the above suggests (to me), that key=whatever in sorted is passing 
#   each element (or nested tuple) from the parent tuple 
#   into the replacable x parameter of the lambda, (which returns element 2.) 
#
#   therefore, I should be able to replace the lambda with a function 
#   that does the same thing, and the key= part of sorted should pass 
#   each tuple to the replacable paramter of the function too.

#--------------------------

#       define a function that should do the same as the lambda
def slice_2(a):
    return a[2]

#--------------------------

print sep, "function, slice_2 on its own for student_tuples"

for line in student_tuples:
    s2 = slice_2(line)
    print s2, type(s2)

#--------------------------

print sep, "sorted should pass data into slice_2 functions replacable paramter"

sf = sorted( student_tuples, key=slice_2(y) )

for l in sf:
    print l


#--------------------------

#################
# end of script #
#################
```

**Here is the output of the script with the exception error:**

```
----------------
plain student_tuples on each line
('john', 'A', 15) <type 'tuple'>
('jane', 'C', 10) <type 'tuple'>
('dave', 'D', 12) <type 'tuple'>

----------------
show lambda is returning element 2 of each nested tuple
15 <type 'int'>
10 <type 'int'>
12 <type 'int'>

----------------
show sorted is passing each tuple to lambda in key=
('jane', 'C', 10)
('dave', 'D', 12)
('john', 'A', 15)

----------------
function, slice_2 on its own for student_tuples
15 <type 'int'>
10 <type 'int'>
12 <type 'int'>

----------------
sorted should pass data into slice_2 functions replacable paramter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compare-tuple-to-function.py", line 88, in <module>
    sf = sorted( student_tuples, key=slice_2(y) )
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `key=slice_2`, not `key=slice_2(y)`. You need to use **the function itself** as the key, not the result of the function being called with a mysterious `y` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks very much for your answer. It works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to give the function (name) as key, not any (y) parameter. The function will automatically be called with the current element as the single parameter.

```
sf = sorted(student_tuples, key=slice_2)
```

This should give the expected output.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your answer as well. ....I did not realise that the function syntax would need to be "key=slice_2" in this situation. (different to using "result = slice_2(y) syntax" elsewhere) --  I am still on a learning curve with Python.... Thanks to both of you

Comment: The difference is this: slice_2(y) calls the function, which then returns a value. So usually, when you do `result=slice_2(y)`, you "simply" assign the return value of the function to the variable result. But here you don't want a specific return value. Instead you want to give the sorted() a function, that can be used to get an ordering. But yes, this may seem strange at first.

Comment: Before your explanation, I was thinking that key= was somehow passing parameters to the function, Now I understand that key=func or key=lambda, is passing the function or lambda to sorted, which is quite a fundamental difference. (so it was well worth the effort for me to try and understand what key= does). Thanks again!